# Prove $\exists A:\forall x: \big(\varphi(x)\implies x\in A\big)$ implies $\{x\in A:\varphi(x)\}$ exists and does not depend on $A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

**Background**: This excersie figured in a [former question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4360313/difficulty-in-reading-introduction-to-set-theory-by-hrbacek).

**What I'd like to know:**

1. Is my proof correct?
2. Are there any simpler proofs for this proposition?

**My attempt (*Proof*).**

Suppose $$\exists A:\forall x:\Big(\varphi(x)\implies x\in A\Big)\tag{1}$$ By applyin the *schema of comprehension* on the set $A$ in $(1)$, $$\exists B: \forall x: \Big(x\in B\iff x\in A \wedge \varphi(x)\Big)\tag{2}$$

where $B=\{x\in A: \varphi(x)\}$. Thus, proving the sought set exists.

To stablish the existing set $B$ does not depend on $A$, let us further assume $$\exists A': \forall x: \Big(\varphi(x)\implies x\in A'\Big) \tag{3}$$ There are two possible cases:

- **Case $i)$** Given any sets $x$, whenever $\varphi(x)$ is true then \begin{align*}\varphi(x)&\implies x\in A\wedge x\in A'\tag*{by $(1)$ and $(2)$}\\
  &\implies  \Big(x\in A\iff x\in A'\Big)\\
  &\implies \Big(x\in A\wedge \varphi(x)\iff x\in A'\wedge \varphi(x)\Big)\\
  &\implies \{x\in A:\varphi(x)\}=\{x\in A':\varphi(x)\}
  \end{align*}
- **Case $ii)$** For an arbitrary chosen set $x$, if $¬\varphi(x)$ then
  \begin{align*}
  ¬\varphi(x)&\implies ¬(x\in A)\wedge ¬(x\in A')\tag*{by $(1)$ and $(2)$}\\
  &\implies A=\emptyset=A'\tag*{by uniqueness of $\emptyset$}\\
  &\implies (x\in A\iff x\in A')\\
  &\implies \{x\in A:\varphi(x)\}=\{x\in A':\varphi(x)\}
  \end{align*}

Hence, the set $B$ does not depend on $A$.

Comment: IMO the proof is quite simple... $\{ x \in A \mid \varphi(x) \}$ is simply $\{ x \mid x \in A \land \varphi(x) \}$. So, if $A$ exists, we have only to apply [Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification#Statement): $\exists B \forall x (x \in B \leftrightarrow [x \in A \land \varphi(x)])$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That would only proof that the set exists, wouldn't that? One can easily show thatset is unique (lemma) so, would that complete the uniqueness proof (using that lemma)?

Answer (score 1):

The latter part of your proof (independence from the choice of $A$) is incorrect.

Consider $\varphi(x)$ to indicate $x\in\{0,1\},$ $A=\{0,1,2\},$ and $A'=\{0,1,3\}.$ Clearly, for $x=2:=\Bigl\{\emptyset,\bigl\{\emptyset\bigr\},\bigl\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\bigl\}\Bigl\},$ we have $\neg\varphi(x).$ However, we *cannot* conclude that $x\notin A.$ Also, for $x=4,$ we have $\neg\varphi(x),$ but while $x\notin A$ and $x\notin A',$ we *cannot* conclude that $A=\emptyset=A'.$

Your first case almost completely does the trick, though it's a bit awkward/ambiguous. I would proceed instead as follows. Let $B:=\{x\in A:\varphi(x)\},$ and assume that $A'$ has the property that $\forall x, \varphi(x)\Longrightarrow x\in A'.$ Show that if $x\in B,$ then $x\in A',$ so that $B\subseteq\{x\in A':\varphi(x)\}.$ An analogous argument shows that $B\supseteq\{x\in A':\varphi(x)\},$ completing the proof.

Comment: Is the following argument correct? Let $B:=\{x\in A:\varphi(x)\}$ and $B':=\{x\in A':\varphi(x)\}$. If $¬\varphi(x)$ then $B=\emptyset=B'$. Meaning, $\{x\in A: \varphi(x)\}=\{x\in A':\varphi(x)\}$. Finally, does the first case do the trick? If it does, I fixed the proof.

Comment: You cannot conclude that $B=\emptyset=B'$ unless you know that *for all* $x,$ $\neg\varphi(x).$ Rather, you can only conclude that for that particular, arbitrary $x,$ we have $x\notin B$ and $x\notin B'.$ Your first case *almost* does the trick. Show instead that $x\in B$ implies that $x\in A$ and $\varphi(x),$ whence $x\in A'$ and $\varphi(x),$ and so $x\in B'.$ Similarly, if $x\in B',$ then $x\in B.$

Comment: How about this? We would have that for that particular, arbitrary $x$, we know both $x\notin B$ and $x\notin B'$. Then, it'll be true that $x\in B\iff x\in B'$, i.e, $B=B'$.

Comment: That's at least doable, I suppose, just a little clunky. If $\varphi(x),$ then $x\in B$ and $x\on B'.$ If $\neg\varphi(x),$ then $x\notin B$ and $x\notin B'.$ Since for all $x$ we have $\varphi(x)$ or $\neg\varphi(x),$ then for all $x$ we have $x\in B$ if and only if $x\in B'.$